# Pandas dataframe: averaging values in one col because another col has duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe similar to below:

```
   Time    B    C  
   10:06   2    5
   10:07   5    3
   10:07   4    1 
   10:08   7    3
   10:08   9    4
   10:08   5    6
```

I want to average the values in cols B and C if the 'times' are equal. I have the following code, but I realized I didn't make a general case of when:
1. no duplicates
2. more than 3 readings within same min

Is there a more efficient and generalized method of doing this?

```
    rowF = len(B)
    while i < rowF -1:

    if (df.loc[i, 'Time'] == df.loc[i+1, 'Time']):
        if(df.loc[i,'Time'] == df.loc[i+2, 'Time']):
            a = df.loc[i:i+2,'B']
            avg = sum(a)/float(len(a))
            average.append(avg)
            print(average)
        else:
            a = df.loc[i:i+1,'B']
            avg = sum(a)/float(len(a))
            average.append(avg)
            print(average)

    df1['B'] = average
    i+=1
```

Expected output:

```
    Time    B     C  
   10:06   2      5
   10:07   4.5    2
   10:08   7     4.3
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Just use `df.groupby('Time', as_index=False).mean()`?

Comment: @Zero I added the expected output. Thank you for the comment; is it possible for you to explain what groupby is doing and can I implement it for a large dataset efficiently?

Comment: See the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) function for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['10:06', '10:07', '10:07', '10:08', '10:08', '10:08'],
                   'B': [2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 5],
                   'C': [5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6]})

df.groupby('Time').mean()
```

This will return the mean of each column, grouped by index value:

```
         B         C
Time
10:06  2.0  5.000000
10:07  4.5  2.000000
10:08  7.0  4.333333
```

Comment: I don't know what is the reason but it did not work for me

Comment: What is the output / error you get when trying this?